# Broadcast a transaction to all peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Can I broadcast a transaction to all peers irrespective of the ORG?

I have a single channel with multiple peers.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When you send a transaction to the ordering service, it is implicitly broadcasted to all peers in the channel. The transaction is going to be included in some future block, and all peers in the channel are going to pull that block and get that transaction.